# Npc animation following player unity 2d top down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, topdown

Hey I am making a top down game in unity. The problem I ma having is making npc players change the way they are facing while following the player. So if the player turns left the npc follows them but doesn't turn to face the direction the npc is going. I can get the npc to look like its walking just not change the direction it is looking. This is a 2d top down game please any help will be nice. here is my npc code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SlimeController : MonoBehaviour
{

public Transform Character; // Target Object to follow
public float speed = 0.1F; // Enemy speed
public float maxDist = 10.0f;
public float attackdistance = 3;
public float farenough;
private Vector3 directionOfCharacter;
private bool challenged = false;// If the enemy is Challenged to follow by the player
public Transform StartMarker;
private Vector3 goback;
public Transform EndMarker;
public Rigidbody2D rb;
Animator anim;
float oldx;
bool left;
bool right;

private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    anim= GetComponent<Animator>();
    oldx = transform.position.x;

}



void Update()
{
    anim.SetBool("left", false);
    anim.SetBool("right", false);
    var distanceFromPlayer = Vector3.Distance(Character.position, transform.position);

    if(oldx>transform.position.x)
    {
        left = false;
        right = true;
    }

    if(oldx<transform.position.x)
    {
        left = true;
        right = false;
    }
    if (oldx == transform.position.x)
    {
        left = false;
        right = false;
    }

    if (challenged)
    {

        directionOfCharacter = Character.transform.position - transform.position;
        directionOfCharacter = directionOfCharacter.normalized;    // Get Direction to Move Towardsss
        transform.Translate(directionOfCharacter * speed, Space.World);
        enabled = true;




        if (distanceFromPlayer < attackdistance)
        {

            attack();
        }

        if (distanceFromPlayer > attackdistance)
        {
            speed = 0.03f;
        }


    }

    if (!challenged)
    {

        goback = StartMarker.transform.position - transform.position;
        goback = goback.normalized;
        transform.Translate(goback * speed, Space.World);

    }
}

// Will be triggered as soon as player would touch the Enemy Object
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == ("Player"))
    {
        challenged = true;

    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == ("Player"))
    {
        speed = 0.03f;
        challenged = false;
    }

}

void attack()
{
    speed = 0;
    transform.Translate(directionOfCharacter * speed, Space.World);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are just moving the object towards your target. But to have it look at your target you need to also rotate it in the direction of your target.

The Transform Component has a function called `LookAt`. You supply it with your Target and the Axis your object should rotate around. So in your case:

```
this.transform.LookAt(Character, Vector3.up);
```

See [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) for more info on `LookAt`.

Comment: I'm not trying to rotate the object just change the animation of it.

Comment: In this case you should look at how to set up [Blend Trees](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BlendTree.html) in your Animator Controller.